# Vue is not a constructor

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue.js, webpack-2

I using `webpack`, after build and run in chrome show this error,I don't know how to solve it.

My code is very simple:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-runtime": "5",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "vue-hot-reload-api": "^2.0.9",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.3",
    "vue-loader": "10.0.3",
    "vue-style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.1.10",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.1.10"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to import vue like this `import Vue from 'vue'`

Comment: Check this tutorial for Vue v3 setup without vue-cli: https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-setup-a-vue-js-project-from-scratch-without-vue-cli/

Comment: For my case I needed to include version of Vue in Url as it is now a requirement for your version in use. For example: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.18/dist/vue.min.js

Answer (score 23):

The issue is that Vue latest library has been updated, so we need to specify the version in the script tag

Please, replace the tag

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>`

By

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you, such a simple thing to miss.

Answer (score 20):

Vue is the default export from that library so you import like this.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

Comment: @BelminBedak thank you, my original code is `import * as Vue from 'vue';` , I change it can work.

Comment: I import Vue like this but it still does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: it worked great, can you please why it didn't work as window.Vue = require('vue');
thank you!

Comment: @salmanifrahim At that point it would depend on your build process, require('vue') does not work in the browser and "SHOULD" be compiled to support both default and primary exports.  If you add require("vue').default it might work, wowever, your best bet is to lean into the ESM import statement like above.

Answer (score 17):

I faced this problem while I was learning Vue. My tutorial was from Vue 2 and I was using Vue 3.

So I solved it by replacing

```
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    message: "Hello Vue!",
  },
});
```

to this

```
const { createApp } = Vue;

createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      message: "Hello Vue!",
    };
  },
}).mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 13):

You need to import the runtime only build. [This comment in the Github issues](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/215#issuecomment-238095102) explains.

Put this in your `webpack.config.js`.

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
  }
}
```

Comment: What can I do if I have no webpack? I only use ts-node to resolve packages.

Comment: @mesqueeb Use `vue/dist/vue.js` in development and `vue/dist/vue.min.js` in production.

Answer (score 4):

i just replace this file

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

in my code and the error ("Vue is not a constructor") is remove