# VueJS: Uncaught TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.default is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am referring https://youtu.be/5lVQgZzLMHc?t=800 to build my first `Vuex` application. This is a 2018 tutorial so my `main.js` looks a bit different. I am using `Vue 3.0.2` (as shown in Vue developer tool).

This is what my `main.js` looks:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

So, I made changes to this file in order to match what is in the tutorial:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

But this gives me the following console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.default is not a constructor
```

I ignored it and went ahead with the tutorial. According to the tutorial I created `store/index.js` file with the following contnet:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import Vue from 'vue';
import todos from './modules/todos';

// Load Vuex
Vue.use(Vuex);

// Create the store
export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        todos
    }
});
```

I also have created `todos.js` file inside `store/modules` directory which looks like this:

```
const state = {
    todos: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Learn Vuex'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Resolve errors'
        }
    ]
};

const getters = {
    allTodos: (state) => state.todos
};

const actions = {};

const mutations = {};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

Then I modified my `main.js` like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue'
import todos from './store'

new Vue({
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

And now the error changes to this:

```
index.js?4360:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined
```

I am only a learner of Vue in very early stage. Cannot figure out how I can resolve these issues, especially with the changes in syntax and pattern of `main.js` file.

*UPDATE*
If I have understood correctly , the boilerplate (`vue create .`) did not add any `webpack` dependency in the project.

```json
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vuex": "^3.5.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0"
},
```

Looks like [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51601615/1496518) that having `Webpack` dependency is not mandatory. But I cannot go further with this because I don't know what to do.

Comment: That tutorial uses a previous Vue version. You are using Vue 3. These are exactly the things that are changed in Vue 3. Consider taking another newer tutorial or use Vue : "^2.6.0" and upgrade later when you have more experience.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Maybe I should not request this, but would you please help me by pointing to a tutorial focusing Vue 3?

Comment: You could try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-E0UB-YDRk for example.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will follow this.

Comment: Check this tutorial for Vue v3 setup without vue-cli: https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-setup-a-vue-js-project-from-scratch-without-vue-cli/